# Testing Consul in two datacenter mode

Tags: java, vagrant, consul

We're integration testing a Java application which uses Consul for Service Discovery.  [The Embedded Consul examples](https://github.com/pszymczyk/embedded-consul#passing-custom-configuration) bootstrap a Consul server in a single datacenter, which works well for most of our testing.  However, we're trying to test a situation in which a service record exists in one datacenter and not another.  The [consul guide](https://www.consul.io/intro/getting-started/join.html) uses vagrant to create virtual environments for each datacenter, but this seems difficult to do in an automated testing environment.

Is this the only way to have a consul cluster running locally and simulating two datacenters?  Can the Embedded Consul library do this behind the scenes for us, or do we need to invoke vagrant in our integration testing configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately the issue was that the `-data-dir` needs to be different for each instance:

```
consul agent -server -data-dir=/tmp/consul/node1 -node=agent-tpc -bind=127.0.0.1 -client==127.0.0.1 -datacenter=tpc
consul agent -server -data-dir=/tmp/consul/node2 -node=agent-cnj -bind=127.0.0.2 -client==127.0.0.2 -datacenter=cnj –retry-join-wan=127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run multiple consul processes on a single machine (on different ports and with different data dirs). datacenter is passed in the configuration or as a command line argument. you don't need to use Vagrant at all.. it should be very simple with Docker..

here is an example docker-compose.yml file - https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/master/demo/docker-compose-cluster/docker-compose.yml